# How to encapsulate several cubes in a larger cube using the smallest possible bounds?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bounding-box

I am generating many cubes during runtime and applying some photos to them (it's a type of VR photo browser). Anyway, I am trying to encapsulate them all in a larger cube using the smallest possible bounding box of all the little cubes. This is what I have so far.

After generating all the cubes, the first thing I do is center them all on their parent so the user can position and rotate them relative to the center.

```
     Transform[] children = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
     Vector3 newPosition = Vector3.zero;
     foreach (var child in children)
     {
         newPosition += child.position;
         child.parent = null;
     }
     newPosition /= children.Length;
     gameObject.transform.position = newPosition;
     foreach (var child in children)
     {
         child.parent = gameObject.transform;
     }
```

Then I calculate the bounds of all the cubes which are children of the parent.

```
     Renderer[] meshes = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
     Bounds bounds = new Bounds(transform.position, Vector3.zero);
     foreach (Renderer mesh in meshes)
     {
         bounds.Encapsulate(mesh.bounds);
     }
     Bounds maximumScrollBounds = bounds;
```

Then I create the new larger (red/transparent) cube which will encapsulate all the smaller ones and use the bounds I previously calculated for it's scale.

```
     GameObject boundingBox = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
     Destroy(boundingBox.GetComponent<Collider>());
     boundingBox.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = Resources.Load("Materials/BasicTransparent") as Material;
     boundingBox.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color32(255, 0, 0, 130);
     boundingBox.name = "BoundingBox";
     boundingBox.transform.localScale = new Vector3(maximumScrollBounds.size.x, maximumScrollBounds.size.y, maximumScrollBounds.size.z);
     boundingBox.transform.localPosition = maximumScrollBounds.center;
     boundingBox.transform.SetParent(transform);
```

But the problem is the encapsulating cube is always slightly too big and I cannot figure out why.

[image]

I need it to basically only reach the very edges of the smaller cubes inside of it.

Comment: Can it be that any of the cubes is rotated so that it might be affecting the encapsulation?

Comment: However as far as I am seeing in the picture if they are all same size and axis aligned, event if that could affect, it should not for the shown cube layout...

Comment: I was aware that rotation could be a contributing factor, which is why I encapsulated the mesh renderer bounds instead of the collider bounds which is supposed to address that. But I have also made sure to remove any potential rotation changes anyway to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things I would try:

1.- I believe `Bounds.Encapsulate` retrieves the center in world space. So I think that:

`boundingBox.transform.localPosition = maximumScrollBounds.center;`

Needs to be subtituted by:

`boundingBox.transform.position = maximumScrollBounds.center;`

2.- Its the same, but just to give ideas to try with local/global space, I would also try:

`boundingBox.transform.localPosition = boundingBox.transform.InverseTransformPoint(maximumScrollBounds.center);`

On the other hand I would give a look and check all the faces of the bounding box to check if the over extension of the volume is simmetrical. Also draw the center, to try to narrow the problem and check if its more in the extents or just in the center.

As far as I can guess it is a misplaced center of the obtained bounding box, but for that to be, the exceeding volume in one side should be lacking in the other, so if that is not the problem, that could be an interesting update to move on towards the solution.

Comment: Hmm, if I remove my code centering my children on the parent, [it aligns the bounding box perfectly on one corner of my cubes](https://i.imgur.com/gkC341p.png). I think that code isn't centering the children 100% accurately on the parent so when I call Bounds bounds = new Bounds(transform.position, Vector3.zero), the center point is off...could that be related...?

Comment: I think that [mesh.bounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-bounds.html) retrieves the bounds in local space (so the center is near to 0,0,0) , and you need to provide the center in world space when you encapsulate. Can you check that out? –

Comment: Well since I move the children locally to around the center of the parent, I thought "transform.position" would be the center of the parent in world space? Am I confused?

Comment: try to start that to `Vector3.zero` and encapsulate only the children. If the script is in the parent gameObject, and `transform.position` is this parent gameObject position, that might be messing the encapsulation up if the parent gameobject deos not need to be encapsulated

Comment: That is how it works, but the parent is not being encapsulated as it is just an empty gameobject with no mesh. I double checked to see what was being encapsulated and it was only the children. But I still feel like I am missing something obvious somewhere.

Comment: if the parent is not being encapsulated you should start your bounds with `Vector3.zero` or with the first children bounds, but not with the parent position. I mean in the `Bounds bounds = new Bounds(transform.position, Vector3.zero);`. I am not sure if it is a big deal, but recently dealt with a similar problem, so just to give ideas to try...

Comment: Solved it. It was two things. 1. Like you said, it should have been `boundingBox.transform.position = maximumScrollBounds.center;` and 2. `boundingBox.transform.localScale = new Vector3(maximumScrollBounds.max.x, maximumScrollBounds.max.y, maximumScrollBounds.max.z);` should be using size not max.